# Reference env variable from host at runtime in "env-file" to be passed to docker image

Tags: docker

Is there a syntax to reference an environment variable from the host in a Docker env-file.

Specifically I'd like to do something like `DOCKER_HOST=${HOSTNAME}` where `HOSTNAME` would come the environment of the machine hosting the docker image.

The above doesn't get any attempt at replacement whatsoever and gets passed into the Docker image literally as `${HOSTNAME}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is generally not done at the image level, but at runtime, on docker run:

See "[How to get the hostname of the docker host from inside a docker container on that host without env vars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29812292/6309)"

```
docker run .. -e HOST_HOSTNAME=$(hostname) ..
```

That does use an environment variable.
You can do so *without* environment variables, [using `-h`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34773236/6309)

```
docker run -h=$(hostname)
```

But that does not work when your docker run is part of a docker compose. See [issue 3840](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3840).