# How can a container connect to a service on the docker host?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

There were two [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808920/how-to-get-the-hostname-of-the-docker-host-from-inside-a-docker-container-on-tha) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808920/how-to-get-the-hostname-of-the-docker-host-from-inside-a-docker-container-on-tha) but they didn't quite answer the question.  But if mods think this is a duplicate, please let me know.

I have a docker-compose.yml file that deploys phpmyadmin.  There is a mysql server hosted locally on the host proper (NOT as a container).

I have a config file for phpmyadmin to connect to my database.  I can't seem to find a domain name for docker host so I've been taking the subnet that the containers deploy on and using the `.1` of the subnet.  For example, initially containers deployed to 172.16.0.0/24 and so I declared in phpmyadmin's configuration to connect to 172.16.0.1

This question was born out of the fact that every time I re-deployed, i.e. issued `docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d` the network address kept changing.  My work around is to explicitly declare the default ipam network subnet, which is a fine workaround and actually preferred because I can then pin mysql user logins to the ip address range.

But given that docker knows to resolve the container service "phpmyadmin" to the container's IP address, I figured there MUST be something for the host so I wouldn't have to re-declare the IP address each time.

So, is there a "hostname" that a container can use to talk to the host or am I stuck using IP addresses?

Edit: I'm using docker on Linux and would very much prefer to not run the container in host mode.

Comment: On native Linux, there isn't a magic hostname like that.  The linked question has a couple of workarounds.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to set `network_mode: "host"` in your compose file for the container. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode.

Alternatively you can use `host.docker.internal` as the url name from within the container, if using Docker for Windows or Docker for Mac.

Comment: Thanks but I'm using docker on Linux.  Though if really like to see this added to Linux in the future.  Also, I would prefer not run in host mode if possible.

Comment: @scuba_mike Ah, well in that case, you should keep an eye on this issue: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264. Until that is done, you'll have to use the IP address. Using a script to pass it in as an environment variable somehow might make it less painful.

Comment: Wow that issue is over a year old!  I figured docker was using some sort of form of dnsmasq to do the name resolution. Any idea what the hold up on the feature is?